# Return records beetwen 2 years in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written this code here I want to The list of the movies released between 1967 and 1995, by displaying only title and year.
But no document is being found even if they accept the condition

```
 db.collection.aggregate({
      "$project": {
        "title": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "$match": {
        "year": {
          "$gt": 1967,
          "$lt": 2020
        }
      }
    })
```

Here is the collection

```
{
    "_id": "movie:90",
    "title": "The Dark Knight Rises",
    "year": 2012,
    "genre": "Science-fiction",
    "summary": "Il y a huit ans, Batman a disparu dans la nuit : lui qui était un héros est alors devenu un fugitif. S'accusant de la mort du procureur-adjoint Harvey Dent, le Chevalier Noir a tout sacrifié au last_name de ce que le commissaire Gordon et lui-même considéraient être une noble cause. Et leurs actions conjointes se sont avérées efficaces pour un temps puisque la criminalité a été éradiquée à Gotham City grâce à l'arsenal de lois répressif initié par Dent.Mais c'est un chat – aux intentions obscures – aussi rusé que voleur qui va tout bouleverser. À moins que ce ne soit l'arrivée à Gotham de Bane, terroriste masqué, qui compte bien arracher Bruce à l'exil qu'il s'est imposé. Pourtant, même si ce dernier est prêt à endosser de nouveau la cape et le casque du Chevalier Noir, Batman n'est peut-être plus de taille à affronter Bane…",
    "country": "USA",
    "director": {
      "_id": "artist:266",
      "last_name": "Nolan",
      "first_name": "Christopher",
      "birth_date": "1970"
    },
    "actors": [
      {
        "_id": "artist:22",
        "first_name": "Morgan",
        "last_name": "Freeman",
        "birth_date": "1937",
        "role": "Lucius Fox"
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to revert the order of your aggregation operations since your `$project` will only leave one property `title` so there is no way to filter by `year` afterwards:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "year": {
                "$gt": 1967,
                "$lt": 2020
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "title": 1,
            "year": 1
        }
    }])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2VffYA8gfha)

Answer (score -1):

```
db.movies.find({year: {$gte:1967, $lte:1995} },{title:1,year:1,"director.last_name":1 }).sort({year:1})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.